# I created a new model signup with appropriate fields which creates users just fine but I am unable to create a log in for the same [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I was following "CodingEntrepreneurs - Try Django Tutorial 5 of 21 - Django Views for the Sign up model" tutorial on YouTube and was able to successfully create a signup model with proper details. After that I wanted to implement sign in feature for the same, so I started following > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4zNUCFtfdY&feature=youtu.be < but I am unable to log in through this process, it is always returning the unable to login page, I am completely lost even though I have spent a lot of time figuring this out on my own.  [This is the project folder.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vEIMMyybm_OUhZMEdEejVPOHM) Any help would be appreciated.

Signin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
     <p> Sorry thats invalid username or password</p>
     {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" action="/auth/">{% csrf_token %}
      <label for="email">E-mail</label><br><input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
      <label for="password">Password</label><br><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">

       <input type="submit" >
     </form>


</body>

</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from .forms import SignUpForm,SignInForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from django.template.context_processors import csrf

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
 return render_to_response('index.html')


def signup(request):
 form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)

 if form.is_valid():
    save_it=form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    messages.success(request,'thanku for joining')


 return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})

def SignIn(request):
 c= {}
 c.update(csrf(request))
 return render_to_response('signin.html',c)

def auth_view(request): 
 if request.method == 'POST':
  email=request.POST['email']
  password=request.POST['password'] 
  user=authenticate(email=email,password=password)

  if user is not None:
   login(request,user)
   return render_to_response('LoggedIn.html')
  else:
   return HttpResponse('<h1>Invalid username/password<</h1>')

from django import forms

from .models import signup
```

Forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = signup
        widgets={
        'password':forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

        fields='__all__'

class SignInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= signup
        widgets={
        'password':forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

        fields='__all__'
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class signup(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="qwerty")
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: you need username to Authenticate user not email.

Comment: use in-built django User model for signup purpose. that would be easy.